# Is there any (hopefully) simple approximation for the Poisson distribution cumulative density function?

Tags: inverse, poisson-distribution

I need the inverse CDF to get the quantiles in an efficient way but I don't find anything on internet. Please help

Comment: Is [`scipy.stats.poisson.cdf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.poisson.html) efficient enough?

Comment: What do you need the approximation for? Perhaps take a peek at Hildebrand's "Short course on asymptotics" (PDF at his homepage) for ideas.

Comment: Does this help? https://i.imgur.com/xPBYde9.png